# jQuery on() method - not working with <input type "submit"> or <button>

Tags: jquery, button, onclick, click

I'm struggeling with the jQuery on("click", function()).

When I create a **button** or **input type="submit"** the width and height in my grid don't change. When I use **h4** for example, it works. What's the problem with it?

I created a jsfiddle to show you what's the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/Mitzi_Rebel/gdsesnpv/6/

I'm completely new to JavaScript and this is my first stackoverflow. Thanks a lot for help!

**HTML**

```html
<form id="sizePicker">
       Grid Height:
       <input type="number" id="input_height" name="height" min="1" value="20">
       Grid Width:
       <input type="number" id="input_width" name="width" min="1" value="20">
    
       <input type="submit" id="size"> //doesn't work
       <button>Button Submit</button>  //doesn't work
       <h4>Überschrift Submit</h4>  //works
     </form>
```

```js
    var height;
    var width;
   
    $(document).ready(function() { 
       $("h4").on("click", function(){
       height = (document.getElementById("input_height").value + "px");
       width = (document.getElementById("input_width").value + "px");
       $("tr").css("height", height);
       $("td").css("width", width);
       });
     });
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gdsesnpv/7/  works for me

Answer (score -1):

You want to use e.PreventDefault when using buttons to prevent the form from being submitted and the page from reloading.

```
$("#size").on("click", function(e){

    height = (document.getElementById("input_height").value + "px");
    width = (document.getElementById("input_width").value + "px");
    $("tr").css("height", height);
    $("td").css("width", width);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```